# Cant connect Ray Dashboard to Grafana and Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, ray

[image]

Prometheus and Grafana set up on the same server and accessible via browser
also i tried set env variable

```
export RAY_GRAFANA_HOST=192.168.0.104:3000
export RAY_GRAFANA_HOST=0.0.0.0:3000 
export RAY_GRAFANA_HOST=192.168.0.104
export RAY_GRAFANA_HOST=http://192.168.0.104
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Per documentation you should be using `RAY_GRAFANA_HOST=http://192.168.0.104:3000`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Have you tried `RAY_GRAFANA_IFRAME_HOST`? Please see https://discuss.ray.io/t/how-can-i-override-the-default-grafana-host-variable/8886/4